# Failed to pass bitmap between activites

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, onactivityresult

I have one Activity process a picture and pass it to it's starting actvity if a save button is pressed.

This is the main activity

```
public class Activity1{
......
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
......
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
......
}
```

This is the second activity which has problem

```
public class Activity2{
.......
mSave = findViewById(R.id.save_button);            
mSave.setOnClickListener((View v)->{
        try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
        getIntent().putExtra("Bitmap Bytes",bytes);
        stream.close();
        mBitmap.recycle();
        this.setResult(RESULT_OK,getIntent());
        this.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

The second activity did not close after calling this.finish() and no activity result recieved by main activity. If I comment out getIntent().putExtra("Bitmap Bytes",bytes) it kind of work but lost its purpose.So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: There's a limit to the amount of data you can pass on an `Intent`, and you shouldn't be passing images like that. Save it to storage instead, and have the other `Activity` read it from there.

Comment: freqent writing and reading to storage is not a good practice,plus I was passing a byte[] that should be just a pointer to the data address right?

Comment: agree with mike. you need to save it some where pass the location of bitmap to the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the size a `Bundle` can have and you are probably exceeding this limit. So you probably go in the `catch` block, therefore the activity will not call `finish()`